# How to upload a file using xmlhttprequest in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, nightwatch.js, form-data

I want to upload file to rest api using xmlhttprequest. But when i am using xhr.send(form) i am getting error 
TypeError: The "string" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer. Received type object

This error is occurring due to this line

```
headers["Content-Length"] = Buffer.isBuffer(data) ? data.length : Buffer.byteLength(data);
```

I am using nightwatch framework

```
 "File Upload": function (client) {
        var length1;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var form = new FormData();


        form.append('file', fs.createReadStream('C:/Users/nikhilb/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot(109).png',{encoding :'UTF-8'}), { filename: '/Screenshots/Screenshot(109).png', contentType: 'image/png' })


        const formHeader = form.getHeaders()


        xhr.open("POST", "https://test.tech/1.0/upload_file", false)
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", `Bearer ${globals.access_token}`)

        xhr.send(form)


        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log("success")
        }
        else {
            console.log("fail", xhr.responseText)
        }




    }
```

Comment: `data.append("file","D:/claimcolony-ui-tests/Files/Note_orgA.png");` imagine if random Ads could upload files from your hard drive without asking you.

Comment: @Thomas Can you please provide the solution. Since i am new to nodejs, i am not able to understand